# trainCascadeObjectDetector FalseAlarmRate - lower or higher?

Tags: matlab

I read info about cascade training in Matlab:

> **Lower values** for FalseAlarmRate increase complexity of each stage.
>   Increased complexity can achieve fewer false detections but can result
>   in longer training and detection times. **Higher values** for
>   FalseAlarmRate can require a greater number of cascade stages to
>   achieve reasonable detection accuracy.

Isn't it should be also **Lower values** in the second sentence? If lower values increases complexity then lower values requires a greater number of cascade stages, not higher ones...

So I'm a little bit confused

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/traincascadeobjectdetector.html
[image]

Comment: increase complexity **of each** stage. I assume hihger values decrease complexity of each stage, but add more stages